# how to create delegate of interface implementation in C for mono runtime?

Tags: c#, c, mono, interop

I am trying to extend library written in c for linux by some c# (or f#) code  using mono.

Simple example of calling c# from c looks quite simple:

```
//c# code, compiled with mcs -t:library Ex1.cs
public static class Ex1 {
  public class Inner {
    public static void someAction(int i) {
      System.Console.WriteLine("some action with " + i);
    }
  }
}

//c code, compiled with gcc ex1.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs mono-2)
#include <mono/jit/jit.h>
#include <mono/metadata/assembly.h>

int main()
{
  MonoDomain *domain = mono_jit_init("Ex1.dll");
  MonoAssembly *assembly = mono_domain_assembly_open(domain, "Ex1.dll");
  MonoImage *image = mono_assembly_get_image(assembly);

  MonoClass *class_ptr = mono_class_from_name(image, "", "Ex1/Inner");
  MonoMethod *class_method = mono_class_get_method_from_name_flags(
      class_ptr, "someAction", 1, 0);

  void *args[1];
  int value = 42;
  args[0] = &value;
  mono_runtime_invoke(class_method, NULL, args, NULL);

  mono_jit_cleanup(domain);
  return 0;
}
```

Running ./a.out we see output from c# library.

But is it possible to implemented interface or at least delegate defined in c# on c side?

For example:

```
//c# compiled mcs -t:library Ex2.cs
public static class Ex2 {
  public interface MyInterface {
    void someAction(int i);
  }

  public delegate void MyDelegate(int i);

  public static class Inner {
    static public void someAction1(MyInterface iface, int value) {
      iface.someAction(value);
    }
    static public void someAction2(MyDelegate d, int value) {
      d(value);
    }
  }
}


//c compiled with gcc ex2.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs mono-2)
#include <mono/jit/jit.h>
#include <mono/metadata/assembly.h>

int main()
{
  MonoDomain *domain = mono_jit_init("Ex2.dll");
  MonoAssembly *assembly = mono_domain_assembly_open(domain, "Ex2.dll");
  MonoImage *image = mono_assembly_get_image(assembly);

  MonoClass *class_ptr = mono_class_from_name(image, "", "Ex2/Inner");
  MonoMethod *class_method1 = mono_class_get_method_from_name_flags(
      class_ptr, "someAction1", 2, 0);
  MonoMethod *class_method2 = mono_class_get_method_from_name_flags(
      class_ptr, "someAction2", 2, 0);

  void *args1[2];
  int value1 = 42;
  args1[0] = NULL;//how to correctly initialize this?
  args1[1] = &value1;
  mono_runtime_invoke(class_method1, NULL, args1, NULL);

  void *args2[2];
  int value2 = 42;
  args2[0] = NULL; //or this?
  args2[1] = &value2;
  mono_runtime_invoke(class_method2, NULL, args2, NULL);

  mono_jit_cleanup(domain);
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Decide on what you're asking, C or C++.

Comment: Fair enough. I change everything to C as mono api is in C.